# Why is my controller function being called so many times?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function in my controller:

```
    $scope.isStageCompleted = function (stage) {
        return stage.StageId < $scope.currentStage.StageId ? "complete" : "pending";
    };
```

It's called in two places in my view:

```
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat="stage in stageList" id="progressStage{{ stage.StageId }}" class="{{ isStageCompleted(stage) }}">{{ stage.StageName }}<span class="sr-only"> {{ isStageCompleted(stage) }}</span></li>
        </ol>
```

Since it's used in two places and there are 10 stages in the stage list I'd expect it to be called 20 times. But it's being called 200 times and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Because the `isStageCompleted()` is triggered on any digest loop

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this or is this correct?

Comment: Can you add it to your `stage` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the result of the function to the `stage` object:

```
$scope.isStageCompleted = function (stage) {
    stage.status = stage.StageId < $scope.currentStage.StageId ? "complete" : "pending";
};
```

And on the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="stage in stageList" id="progressStage{{ stage.StageId }}" class="{{ stage.status }}">{{ stage.StageName }}<span class="sr-only"> {{ stage.status }}</span></li>
```

You can also use one-time binding if you don't need to update the output:

```
<li ng-repeat="stage in stageList" ng-init="isStageCompleted(stage)" id="progressStage{{ stage.StageId }}" class="{{ ::stage.status }}">{{ stage.StageName }}<span class="sr-only"> {{ ::stage.status }}</span></li>
```

Adding `::` before the expression make angular to ignore it in the next digest loops (After the expression output is rendered into the document)

LAST EDIT:

```
<li ng-repeat="stage in stageList" id="progressStage{{ stage.StageId }}" ng-class="{'pending': stage.StageId >= currentStage.StageId, 'complete': stage.StageId < currentStage.StageId}">{{ stage.StageName }}<span class="sr-only"> {{ stage.StageId < currentStage.StageId ? "complete" : "pending" }}</span></li>
```

Comment: One time binding looks cool. But if I use your other solution and save the result to the stage object I'm guessing I'd have to call isStageCompleted in the controller load since it won't be called from the view anymore correct?

Comment: That is correct. I also added another change in my answer, used `ngInit` to reduce the number of calls to the controller

Comment: @Legion Added my final solution, that remove any use of function at all, just a pure angularJS expression solution